# Create a bean at runtime with generic

Tags: spring, generics

I need to programmatically create a spring bean for a spring data. It manage a generic class only known at runtime.
This is my repository definition :

```
@Component
public interface GeneratorRepository<P extends MyType>
        extends Repository<P, Long>
```

And this is how I manage to create a bean :

```
@Autowired
DefaultListableBeanFactory springContextBeanFactory;
RootBeanDefinition beanDefinition = new RootBeanDefinition(GeneratorRepository.class);
        beanDefinition.setTargetType(
                ResolvableType.forClassWithGenerics(GeneratorRepository.class, aMyTypeClassImpl));
        
springContextBeanFactory.registerBeanDefinition(
        aMyTypeClassImpl.getSimpleName() + GeneratorRepository.class.getSimpleName(), beanDefinition);
```

After that, I can get the bean name with something like :

```
String[] name = springContextBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(
                        ResolvableType.forClassWithGenerics(GeneratorRepository.class, aMyTypeClassImpl));
```

And I get the name for the bean that was just created. But I get BeanCreationException when doing :

```
springContextBeanFactory.getBean(beanNamesForType[0])
```

with message :
Failed to instantiate [com.my.project.generator.GeneratorRepository]: Specified class is an interface

The question is : is that possible to programmatically create a bean for an interface with generic and use it to get an Object?

Thank you for reading and for any help !

Answer (score 0):

No, you can`t create an instance of interface. But you can create its implementation in runtime (see ByteBuddy) and then add it as a bean to spring.